# first Div full size of the window, white space

Tags: html, css

**[ONLINE SAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Bc3ye/)**

I wanted to make the first div `layer1` (red block)shows full size of the window, scaleable. 
`Layer2` (blue block) suppose to be always under `layer1`. however, when I make the window height shorter, I found `layer2` goes to in the middle of the `layer1`, please see the image below

[image]

so I tried to apply `overflow:hidden` on `layer1`, but `layer2` the blue area still overlaps on layer1. how to make this in right way. As if change the windows size as the same as mobile phone, it doesn't look right :(

please see the mobile view

[image]

if someone could help. Thanks

HTML

```
   <div class="layer1">
      <h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
    <div class="layer2">
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
</div>
```

css

```
html,body{
  height: 100%;

}
body{
 padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.layer1{
width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
     background:red;

}
.layer2{
  background:blue;
  position:relative;
  top:100%;
}
```

Comment: I did not explain more what you want

Comment: position: absolute is what's cause the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you change your styles to the following

```
html,body{ height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
.layer1{ width: 100%; min-height: 100%; background:red; overflow:auto;}
.layer2{ background:blue; position:relative; overflow:auto;}
```

it should do what you want: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bc3ye/5/)

Answer (score 1):

try this code, it should be working with the HTML example of you.

[live demo](http://jsbin.com/folec/15/edit?html,css,output)

CSS-code

> html,body{
>    height: 100%;}
>
> body{padding: 0;
>      margin: 0;}
>
> .layer1{
>      margin: auto 0;
>      width: 100%;
>      height: 100%;
>      left: 0;
>      top: 0;
>       background:red;}
>
> .layer2{
>    background:blue;
>    top:100%;
>   }

Comment: The text still overflows when red is greater than screen height

Answer (score -1):

Please Replace This css and try it...

```
.layer2{
  background:blue;
  position:relative;
  top:100%;
  width: 80%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```